# SQL CAST with ISNULL results in conversionfailure

Tags: sql-server

I've got a nullable column of numbers, which is unfortunately declared as a `varchar` in the database, and so I want to convert the `NULL` to 0.  Doing this accomplishes that.

```sql
select ISNULL(col, '0')  from table;
```

So now there are no `null` possibilities, and then I want to convert the column to an actual int value, so I tried to wrap that.

```sql
select CAST(ISNULL(col, '0') AS INT) from table
```

When that runs I get a conversion error, as shown below.  I don't understand why, or how to get around this:

> Conversion failed when converting the varchar value 'NULL' to data type int.

Comment: The problem is that there is an actual text `'NULL'` in your column. Replace your IsNull() with `IsNull(NullIf(col, 'NULL'),'0')`, which will convert the text `'NULL'` strings to actual NULL values

Comment: I so need to track down this DBA and shake my fist at him :)  Thank you.

Comment: try_convert() or try_cast() is yet another option

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try like this: Take your `ISNULL` statement **outside**

```
SELECT ISNULL(TRY_CAST(col AS INT),0) AS [col]
FROM SAMPLE_TAB;
```

If this does not help, then please comment your SQL version.